# Pass jwt refresh token in header or body

Tags: jwt, access-token

When access token expires, it should re-issue refresh token.
At this point, I'm a little hesitant which method is better.
For access token, it is passed in HTTP header of every request.

When it comes to refresh tokens -

1. Pass refresh token in HTTP header.
2. Pass refresh token in HTTP POST body(payload).

Which one is recommended?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The jwt specification recommends (but does not require) sending the access tokens in an authorization header of type Bearer. But there is no mention of the refresh tokens.

Refresh tokens are an Oauth2 concept. If you read the [Rfc6749 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6), to refresh an access token, the refresh token is sent using a form parameter in a POST request

> **6.  Refreshing an Access Token**
> ...

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA
```

You can use the example of oauth2 as reference (pass it in the body), although if you do not use oauth2, you have no obligation, so use the method to send that best suits your project.

Comment: [rfc8725 - JWT best current practice](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8725)